# Error: xz compression not available

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, xz

I'm running redhat enterprise v6.6 64bit and am tyring to install 32bit Skype.  In the process of trying to fix the dependency issue I managed to create another issue for myself.  When I try and install the i686 dependencies I now get the following:

```
[root@MYSERVER /]# yum install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 
freetype.i686 \glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 
\libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 \pulseaudio-
libs.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686 qtwebkit.i686
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
Error: xz compression not available
```

Comment: Do you have `xz` installed from the RHEL repos?

Comment: [root@MYSERVER tmp]# rpm -qa | grep -i xz
xz-libs-4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6.x86_64
xz-4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6.x86_64
xz-lzma-compat-4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6.x86_64

Comment: Question should be: 1. Which dependency issue did you want to fix in the first place and what did you do to *fix* it? 2. Which repos do you have configured currently? Please show the output of `yum check` and `yum repolist`

Comment: [root@MYSERVER ~]# yum check  
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager  
check all  

[root@MYSERVER ~]# yum repolist  
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager  
HHC_RHEL6-6                                              |  951 B     00:00  
epel/metalink                                            |  13 kB     00:00  
epel                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00  
epel/primary_db                                          | 3.6 MB     00:03  
Error: xz compression not available

Answer (score -1):

```
yum install pyliblzma
```

That installs the package you're missing.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Some dependencies installed however there seems to be a problem with a URL:

Comment: http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/misc-testing/el6Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: nux-misc-testing. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: [root@MYSERVER ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/nux-misc.repo
[nux-misc]
name=Misc Nux.Ro EL6 RPMs
baseurl=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/misc/el$releasever/$basearch/ http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/misc/el$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro

[nux-misc-testing]
name=Misc Nux.Ro EL6 RPMs - testing
baseurl=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/misc-testing/el$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro

Comment: I commented out the nux-misc.testing and tried installing the first dependency listed from the installation steps  -->  
[root@CRPVLX1MIKEADM1 ~]# yum install alsa-lib.i686
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
nux-misc | 2.9 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
After all the dependencies are listed it ultimately ends with the following line: --->  
Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-22.el6_6.x86_64

Comment: the error about the multilib versions means the .i686 and .x86_64 should be the same version. <br/>
<br/>
    maybe try :  
    package-cleanup --dupes  
    package-cleanup --cleandupes  
    yum clean all  
    yum update

Comment: [root@MYSERVER ~]# package-cleanup --dupes
Loaded plugins: product-id  <br/> <br/>
[root@MYSERVER ~]# package-cleanup --cleandupes
Loaded plugins: product-id
No duplicates to remove
[root@MYSERVER ~]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Cleaning repos: HHC_RHEL6-6 epel epel6 nux-dextop nux-misc
Cleaning up Everything

Comment: [root@MYSERVER ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Update Process
HHC_RHEL6-6
HHC_RHEL6-6/primary
HHC_RHEL6-6
epel/metalink
epel
epel/primary_db
epel6/metalink
epel6
epel6/primary_db
nux-dextop
nux-dextop/primary_db
nux-misc
nux-misc/primary_db
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package b43-firmware.noarch 0:5.10.56.27.3-2.el6 will be obsoleting
---> Package b43-openfwwf.noarch 0:5.2-4.el6 will be obsoleted
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

Package Arch Version RepositorySize

Comment: Installing:
b43-firmware      noarch      5.10.56.27.3-2.el6         nux-dextop      109 k
replacing  b43-openfwwf.noarch 5.2-4.el6

Transaction Summary
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 109 k
Is this ok [y/N]:y

Comment: Downloading Packages:
b43-firmware-5.10.56.27.3-2.el6.noarch.rpm               | 109 kB     00:00
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 85c6cd8a: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
Importing GPG key 0x85C6CD8A:
 Userid : Nux.Ro (rpm builder) <rpm@li.nux.ro>
 Package: nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch (installed)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
Is this ok [y/N]:y

Comment: Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : b43-firmware-5.10.56.27.3-2.el6.noarch                       1/2
  Erasing    : b43-openfwwf-5.2-4.el6.noarch                                2/2
  Verifying  : b43-firmware-5.10.56.27.3-2.el6.noarch                       1/2
  Verifying  : b43-openfwwf-5.2-4.el6.noarch                                2/2

Installed:
  b43-firmware.noarch 0:5.10.56.27.3-2.el6

Replaced:
  b43-openfwwf.noarch 0:5.2-4.el6

Complete!

Comment: Still same issue however: --->  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:
  Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-17.el6.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-22.el6_6.x86_64

Comment: can you try "yum update nss-softokn-freebl" to see if it will get the i686 and x86_64 packages to match up, then try the yum install from your first post (also you might want to start another question since the xz compression not available was fixed)